# Enum.KeyCode.GreaterThan is not giving input

Tags: roblox

I'm making admin for my game and the prefix is the greater than sign (>), it is binded by context action service and when you press > it will open the admin bar. But it's not working, I tried disabling mouselock and disabling emotes menu but it still doesn't work.

Code:

```
local cas = game:GetService("ContextActionService")
local ts = game:GetService("TweenService")

cas:BindAction("PrefixPressed", function(_, inputState)
    if inputState == Enum.UserInputState.Begin then
        --tween
    end
end, true, Enum.KeyCode.GreaterThan)
```

Comment: You might have found a bug. Might have to use a different keycode until it's fixed

Comment: Should I send it to the roblox support?

Comment: If you have access to the [DevForum's Engine Bugs forum](https://devforum.roblox.com/c/bug-reports/engine-bugs/28), that's a good place to report it. But if not, I can send it in.

Comment: I cant access it